# How to prevent screen reposition when linking to tab

Tags: html, internal-link

I have an issue I have linked to tab on the same page but I do not want my screen to move to the top when clicked. Can someone help please?

Best Regards

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using please?

Comment: Can't be done without javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I'd wager this is because the link you are clicking on has a href attribute with value `#` or similar. `#` will send you to the top of the page, `#whatever` will send you to the top of the element with ID `whatever` (probably the element containing the tab contents). In order to stop this from happening, you need to put `return false;` at the end of your JavaScript function to prevent the default behaviour from occurring. But without seeing any code, I can't help further.

Comment: It is just simple <ul class="nav_design">
                                    <li class="tester" id="nav_design1"><a href="#tab1">What ever</a></li> and no jq thanks for help anyway

Comment: Like I said, linking to `#tab1` is going to be moving you to the top of the #tab1 element which is probably what contains the tab content, which could well be the top of the page. There will be JavaScript controlling this, and you need to figure out what that JavaScript is in order to instruct it not to follow through with the default behaviour.

Comment: Cool but is there a code that prevent that scroll and keeps the page in focus? I have searched all over the google and seem not being able to find the answer. I know how to prevent the scroll all together with #/ but not other?